# Sublime Text 3 locate default build systems on OS X

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I cannot figure out where to find the default Sublime Text 3 build systems. I would like to see how the default `C++` build system looks like so I can create a `C++11`-compliant out of it. In Sublime 2 the `sublime-build` files were located somewhere in `Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`, however I cannot find anymore the location for Sublime 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pristine packages in OS X are located in `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages`. If you're going to be fooling around with the contents of them, I very strongly recommend using the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. It does all the moving, unzipping, and renaming behind the scenes, and if you set the `"single_command": false` option you'll get all the options you need in the Command Palette. I can't recommend it enough, it's made my life so much easier!

(No, I didn't write it...)

One more bit of advice - don't change any of the pristine packages. Other stuff depends on them, and weird things can break in unexpected ways if you outright delete any of them. Instead, use PRV, and/or create identically-named folders in your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` folder, and override individual files by placing modified versions there instead.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I wasn't able to find the answer on SO, although I now see it was a dupe.

Comment: You might also want to check out [`C++ Starting Kit`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/C%2B%2B%20Starting%20Kit) and/or [`C++11`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/C%2B%2B11) for ideas, and perhaps better (at least different) syntax highlighting than the Sublime default.